# React Native Weird android behaviour displaying uploaded images

Tags: android, image, react-native

We are building an app using React Native and the react-native-image-picker library.

I'll start with the behavior we have right now:
(On Android device) When uploading an image (profile image) selected by the image picker library there are no errors everything goes smooth.
After the request when going back to the profile page the image we just uploaded is not being loaded. Restarting/building/clearing cache does nothing to resolve the problem.

When looking on my iOS simulator/android emulator on the same account I do see the image uploaded from the device.

tl:dr I upload an image from an android device, (Uploaded correctly, can see it in browser) Can't see it on that same device but I can see it on other devices/simulators.

I have no idea what is going on, Would love a fast answer as the problem is delaying a release.

Here is where I get the image from the image picker.

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
  if (response.error) {
    this.props.setError(I18n.t('editProfile.fields.profileImage.error'));
  } else if (!response.didCancel) {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      const image = {
        uri: response.uri.replace('file://', ''),
        filename: 'ProfileImage',
        height: response.height,
        isStored: false,
        width: response.width,
      };

      this.props.onSubmit(image);
    } else {
      const image = {
        uri: response.path,
        filename: 'ProfileImage',
        height: response.height,
        isStored: true,
        width: response.width,
      };

      this.props.onSubmit(image);
    }
  }
});
```

Note: This functionality works perfectly on iOS.

Comment: what uri are you using to display the submitted image?

Comment: I'm using a amazone s3 url.

Comment: The on submit button is an upload function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was caused based on what image was uploaded.
There seems to be a problem with older android devices.

Comment: I have the same issue, it is not possible to display the captured images in Andorid, it works perfectly in iOS, can you share how exactly you solved it please?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with AWS S3 but in my case the problem was that the content-type / mime type was not being set. I had to manually set it.

This is part of my code:

```
s3 = new AWS.S3();

      var extension = ".jpg";
      if (img.mime.indexOf(".png") > -1)
        extension = ".png";

      var key = "Reports/" + req.body.id + "/" + date.getTime() + "/Image" + extension;

      var buf = new Buffer(img.data,'base64');

      var params = {
        Bucket: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        Key: key,
        Body: buf,
        ContentEncoding: 'base64',
        ContentType: img.mime,
        ACL: 'public-read'
      };

      console.log("S3 Start");
      var upload = s3.upload(params, function(err,data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err, err.stack);
        } else {
          console.log(data);
          s3Url = data.Location;
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause it to not show up on the other devices?

Comment: I remember that what was happening to me is that the image was being downloaded instead of showing up because it was detected as an octect binary. But some browsers actually showed the image. I only mention this because you said you were using S3. Is the image actually uploaded correctly?

Comment: Yeah the image is uploaded correctly, It show up on other devices and simulators.